# Thread-safety in Netty threads serving different (but not co-existing) Channels

Tags: java, multithreading, netty

I have an application that uses Netty with NIO. The client creates a `Bootstrap` like this:

```
Bootstrap clientBootstrap = new Bootstrap();

clientBootstrap.group(clientWorkerGroup)
        .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
        .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, clientConfiguration.soKeepAlive())
// and so on
```

where `clientWorkerGroup` is created like this: `new NioEventLoopGroup(threadFactory)`. This produces an event loop group with a default number of threads which is greater than 1, so concurrency between 'client Netty threads' is possible.

The application creates `Channel`s (to servers) from time to time. Implementations of `ChannelOutboundHandler` and `ChannelInboundHandler` are added to the pipeline when a `Channel` is opened; both the inbound and outbound handlers access some common mutable state (the most interesting part of this state is a non-thread-safe `Queue`), access to this state is not synchronized. Each state object corresponds at most to one active `Channel` at a time.

If I understand correctly, this means that, while a `Channel` is alive, the inbound/outbound handlers that correspond to it work in the same thread, so there should be no multi-threading issues. (1)

But after an existing `Channel` gets closed, another one might be opened and (according to the application logic) be assigned a state object with which an earlier `Channel`'s handlers worked. So handlers of the new `Channel` will now access a pre-existing state object, probably in a thread different from the one that was used by the handlers of the first `Channel`. (2)

I would like to ask the following:

1. Is what I described in the paragraph marked with (1) true? That is, if a state object is only accessed by handlers of the same `Channel` (and the channel does not get re-registered, never changes its event loop), does this guarantee thread-safety wrt these state objects?
2. If different channels (but never at the same time) access the same state object (as described in (2)), does this break the guarantee, or Netty somehow manages to still provide it?
3. If the guarantee is broken, is there a way to reestablish it (but without paying the costs of explicit synchronization on the state objects and/or concurrency primitives like concurrent collections)?

Comment: 1) should be correct, all the pipeline callbacks are on a single thread. But sending data can be triggered from all threads and whatever else fills  / drains your queue might also be a different thread. 2) and 3) cannot be answered without a detailed analysis of the code because the only thing netty does is to keep callbacks on a single thread, it can't guarantee you really anything once there is shared data. For 2) you might get away with strict happens-before guarantees but it's easy to break those. For 3) what's so bad about synchronization? Have you benchmarked?